# Heroku: How to Force Throwing a H12 Error?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, error-handling

My website has been getting [H12 errors](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h12-request-timeout) (An HTTP request took longer than 30 seconds ) occasionally but I have been unable to recreate the error. I'm wanting to force the site to return an H12 error, or simply timeout. I'm hoping to be able to do this in order to test what happens when it times out and implement a solution.

How would I go about this?

Here is my route if helpful. Note: I'm using AJAX (not shown)

```
    router.post("/career-test", async function (req, res) {
      
    try {
    let existingUser = await User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
    
    if (!existingUser) {
    let newUser = new User({username: req.body.username });
    
    User.register(newUser, req.body.password, async function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
    req.flash('error', err.message);
    return res.redirect('back');
    } else {    
    user.updated = true;
}
    
req.login(existingUser, function(err) {
if(err) {
req.flash('error', err.message);
return res.redirect('back');
}
res.redirect("/results");
})
    
}
} catch (err) {
req.flash('error', err.message);
}
});
```

Comment: Check out this link : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/addressing-h12-errors-request-timeouts.  Also have you reviewed your logs?

Comment: Thanks @Ezani! I have. I've also taken steps to reduce the H12 errors. However as of now when a user gets a H12 error they just get taken to a heroku error page. I'd like to be able to test this and improve the experience